# Checkbox inside a ListView keep changing their values on activity resume without any logic

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I've a ListActvity which uses a custom cursor adapter. In every row I've a checkbox. When I click on a row another activity starts. If I click the checkbox, it has to select the checkbox and it doesn't have to start any activity.

All of this works.

But the following is happening: if I select some checkboxes, then click on a row, wait for the new activity, then click the back button to go back to the ListActivity, checkboxes resume their status without any logic. Who was checked is now unchecked, who was unchecked is not checked... apparently random.

Here is the CursorAdapter class I'm using (at the end I try to restore the right checkbox values):

```
public class EmailCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String[] from;
    int[] to;

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(this.DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ITALY);

    public EmailCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

        this.context=context;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;

        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        Cursor c = this.getCursor();

        c.moveToPosition(position);

        ViewHolder vh;

        if(v == null) {
            v = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_adapter_row, parent, false);

            vh = new ViewHolder();

            v.setTag(vh);
        }
        else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        vh.position = position;
        vh.database_id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MailDBHelper.MAIL_ID));

        if (this.from.length == this.to.length) {
            int i, size = this.from.length;
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(this.to[i]);

                if (this.from[i].equals(MailDBHelper.MAIL_DATE)) {
                    Timestamp tm = new Timestamp(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MailDBHelper.MAIL_DATE)));
                    String s = this.sdf.format(new Date(tm.getTime()));
                    tv.setText(s);
                }
                else {
                    tv.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(this.from[i])));
                }
            }
        }

        int unseen = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MailDBHelper.MAIL_NEW));
        View box = v.findViewById(R.id.email_row_box);
        if (unseen == MailDBHelper.MAIL_READ) { 
            box.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.seen_email_background));
        }
        else {
            box.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////////
        // HERE I TRY TO RESTORE THE RIGHT VALUE
        //////////////////////////////////////////
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.email_row_check);

        cb.setChecked(vh.isChecked);

        Log.d("DEBUG", "checkbox at position " + position +" is " + cb.isChecked());

        return v;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public int database_id;
        public int position;
        public boolean isChecked;
    }

}
```

I'm using the `ViewHolder` class to get track of the current status of the checkbox. This is the `onListItemClick()` method of my activity:

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        int email_id = vh.database_id;

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.email_row_check);
        vh.isChecked = cb.isChecked();

        if (vh.isChecked) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "checkbox at position " + vh.position + " is checked: true");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "checkbox at position " + vh.position + " is checked: false");
        }

        this.read_email.putExtra("email_id", email_id);
        this.startActivity(this.read_email);
    }
```

From the log in this method it seems it takes the right position and the right checkbox value, and store it in the right ViewHolder.

**EDIT**

Here comes the `getView()` method modified according to Rashmi answer.

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

            Cursor c = this.getCursor();

            c.moveToPosition(position);

            ViewHolder vh;

            if(v == null) {
                v = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_adapter_row, parent, false);

                vh = new ViewHolder();

                vh.cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.email_row_check);
                vh.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ShowEmails.this);

                v.setTag(vh);
            }
            else {
                vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            vh.position = position;
            vh.database_id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MailDBHelper.MAIL_ID));

            if (this.from.length == this.to.length) {
                int i, size = this.from.length;
                for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(this.to[i]);

                    if (this.from[i].equals(MailDBHelper.MAIL_DATE)) {
                        Timestamp tm = new Timestamp(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MailDBHelper.MAIL_DATE)));
                        String s = this.sdf.format(new Date(tm.getTime()));
                        tv.setText(s);
                    }
                    else {
                        tv.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(this.from[i])));
                    }
                }
            }

            int unseen = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MailDBHelper.MAIL_NEW));
            View box = v.findViewById(R.id.email_row_box);
            if (unseen == MailDBHelper.MAIL_READ) { 
                box.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.seen_email_background));
            }
            else {
                box.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }

            return v;
        }
```

The `OnCheckedChangeListener` associated to the checkbox is implemented in the main activity class and it is:

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean isChecked) {
        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)((View)btn.getParent()).getTag();

        vh.cb.setChecked(isChecked);
    }
```

Now, the behavior is different: as soon as I click on a list item, the checkbox rearrange themselves randomly, the new activity starts and when I come back they are back to the right position. Is this code wrong or the problem it's likely to be somewhere else?

Comment: Holding a value in a ViewHolder instance is your problem :) cb.setChecked(vh.isChecked); and you should decide to check or not in other way (like in Rashmi's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well in addition to viewholder pattern you will need few things extra to make your checkbox adapter to work.

I am providing you the pseudo code for how to solve this problem

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cuisine_grid_item, parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.chkCuisine = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkMenu);
            view.setTag(holder);

            holder.chkCuisine.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean val) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    int checkedItem = (Integer) btn.getTag();
                    cuisineList.get(checkedItem).setChecked(val);
                }
            });


        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Cuisine cuisine = cuisineList.get(position);
        holder.chkCuisine.setText(cuisine.getCuisineName());
        holder.chkCuisine.setTag(position);
        holder.chkCuisine.setChecked(cuisine.isChecked());
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to change my code according to your example, but now I've a slightly different problem: the checkboxes rearrange themselves before the new activity is started and they come back to the right values when I go back to the ShowEmails activity. Question edited to show relevant changes.